# ubuntu 15.04 not detecting my external hard disk

Tags: external-hdd

ubuntu 15.04 not detecting my external hard disk. And also everything runs very slow. When i start ubuntu screen flickers with different colours and when i click flies ya settings it takes ages to open(like more than 1 minute). I am using lenovo y50-70

Answer (score 0):

Why would you install a version of Ubuntu which is no longer being supported? I'd suggest installing the recently released 15.10 Version right away.